# On start servos rotates to 180 degree

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, servo, speed

I'm testing a servo using varspeedservo.h and it rotates to 180 degree on start and then rotates back to programmed position. 
Here is the code:

```
#include <AFMotor.h>
#include <VarSpeedServo.h>
VarSpeedServo myServo;

void setup()
{
  myServo.attach(10);
}
void loop()
{
  myServo.slowmove(0, 30);
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: It should not show such behavior. How can i fix it?

Comment: I suspect its finding its limits.  You could try setting the position to 0 before you attach (no idea if that will work)

Comment: I just tried it but not working. Seems this issue comes only when I'm using Varspeedservo.h.

Comment: could it be reversed, try setting it to 180 and see if it moves towards zero, if so just map it map(pos, 0,180,180,0) and success

Comment: I tried reversing but it works fine. Not moving back to 0 deg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to open up the [VarSpeedServo library source code](https://github.com/netlabtoolkit/VarSpeedServo) and read through it to understand how the library actually works with your sketch.

Consider that you have not setup an initial position before issuing your first "slow moving" command.  It may be by setting an initial position before assigning a pin to the servo, you may prevent any unexpected movement.

Try something (for your code) like "myServo.wirte(0,0)" where the first argument is the position and second is the speed.

Comment: I added `myServo.write(0,0);` before `attaching` and it's working fine. Thank you.